# jenkins how can create some container with pushed tag, called like name_v0.01?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, tags, git-push

I have a project on a github and I want to push a tag so that jenkins create a container with a tag and then later send the result to another container. 
I'm newbie into jenkins, use trigger (When developer push a new tag, than create job). But I don’t know how to put the tag name in any variable, then use it to create a container.
For tests, right now I am trying to send the value of a variable to a telegram, but for now I cannot

```
TOKEN=
CHAT_ID=
MESSAGE=$NameTag
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"

curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$CHAT_ID -d text="$MESSAGE"
```

Execute shell I want to do something like this
docker build -t name_container_+$NameTag .

[image]

Comment: GIT_BRANCH contain "origin/tags/v0.05" and via  |  's/.*\///' can get "v0.05"

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which environment variables the git plugin populates, its listed [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), section *Environment Variables*. See if `GIT_BRANCH` contains what you need.